# How to find the list of python virtual envs in C drive?

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtual

In cdrive(C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe), how to find the list of python virtual environments created/installed in the system. This is not in conda environment. I have tried googling but not getting answer for this question

I tried googling for this question and checked in stackoverflow as well

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any command that makes that exactly, but you can create a simple python code to search for it in a given path.

Knowing that in every python env is a config file called "[pyenv.cfg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments)", you can search for it and if you found one it means in that path is a python env.

Here is a simple example code (change "Path-to-search" for the path you need, be careful in windows with the escape of the dash ''):

```py
from pathlib import Path

pathlist = Path('Path-to-search').glob('**/pyvenv.cfg')
for path in pathlist:
     print(str(path))
```